# If Sheet Exists, run sub. If not, display message and exit sub

Tags: vba, excel, boolean

I am stuck despite looking up this topic on other threads.  I would like help with the following:

If the macro can find a sheet named "Transfers," I would like it to activate that sheet and run the rest of the sub, which makes "Transfers" the last sheet.

If it can't find a sheet named "Transfers", I would like it so put up a message (Please make sure that you renamed your data sheet : 'Transfers'") and exit the sub.  My code below is not working.

```
Sub Double_Transfer_Report()
Dim er As Boolean
er = False

On Error Resume Next
'Worksheets("Transfers").Activate
er = true

If er Then
MsgBox ("Please make sure that you renamed your data sheet : Transfers)
Exit Sub
End If

ActiveSheet.Move _
After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
```

Comment: `If er Then` can be rewritten as `If True Then` - it's completely unconditional, compile-time constant, regardless of whether or not an error occurred. `On Error Resume Next` means exactly what it says: if there's an error, the next line executes regardless - so you need to check `Err.Number` *somewhere* in order to have a useful condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is to attempt to activate the worksheet, and if this fails, take note than an error has occurred.

You can modify your code as shown below. The modification pertains to the way your `er` variable gets its value. After the `Activate` method fails, the `Err` object will contain the error number (and other details) until another error occurs or another `On Error` statement is encountered (among other things). Setting `er`, a boolean, to the logical test `Err.Number <> 0` will detect that an error has occurred.

```
Sub Double_Transfer_Report()
    Dim er As Boolean

    er = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("Transfers").Activate
    er = (Err.Number <> 0)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If er Then
        MsgBox "Please make sure that you renamed your data sheet : Transfers)"
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Move After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't do the gymnastic with error object. Just check if the sheet exists or not through looping.

---

```
Sub Double_Transfer_Report()
    Dim found As Boolean

    found = SheetExists("Transfers")

    If Not found Then
        MsgBox "Please make sure that you renamed your data sheet : Transfers"
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Move After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    End If
End Sub

Function SheetExists(strSheetName As String) As Boolean

    Dim wks As Worksheet

    For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        If wks.Name = strSheetName Then
            SheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    SheetExists = False

End Function
```

Comment: That works, but is uselessly inefficient if the workbook contains many, many sheets. Kudos for abstracting away the logic into its own dedicated function though.

Comment: Agreed, it does add a layer of execution. But with 1200 sheets, its taking no time to find sheet's existence. If we have more sheets than that, then there are bigger problems to deal with. :)

Comment: It's a pity the Excel collections don't expose an Exists method.

Comment: @Excelosaurus it's the excel's limitations that keep the job interesting. :)

Comment: There will only be four or five sheets, so this will work.  Thanks!

Comment: @Excelosaurus to be fair, implementing a collection class that does and can be used as a replacement for `VBA.Collection`, isn't all that hard either... but yeah ;-)

Comment: The function can be even simpler if you use the `On Error Resume Next` logic in the function. No looping. Just one quick check and turn back error handling to normal state.

Comment: @Mat's Mug: I was thinking about the built-in ones: Workbooks, Worksheets, etc. In my .NET projects, I've created extension methods. @Scott Holtzman: agree, besides you can generalize with something like  `ItemExists(coll As Object, itemName As String) As Boolean`.

Comment: @Excelosaurus right. except .net has it covered already: `using System.Linq;` -> `Enumerable.Contains` ;-)

Comment: @Mat's Mug well I prefer `Exists` Mr. Smarty pants :D

Answer (score 0):

If you can spare two cells somewhere, you can avoid both looping and error handling, say we use **B1** and **B2**.  In **B1** place the proposed worksheet name and fill **B2** using:

```
Range("B2").Value = "=ISNUMBER(ROWS(INDIRECT(""'""&B1&""'!A1"")))"
```

Then check the Boolean result in **B2**:

[image]

Comment: Interesting approach! The fact that `INDIRECT()` is a volatile function turns me down somewhat, though.

Comment: @Excelosaurus I agree.........I just posted as an alternative to the usual methods.

Comment: You could save two of those two cells by checking `Evaluate("ISNUMBER(ROWS('" & worksheetName & "'!A1))")` where `worksheetName` is a variable containing the name of the worksheet. ;)

Comment: @YowE3K  That is a great idea!

Answer (score 0):

Just another approach, not saying that it is any better than Cyboashu's (or else's answer).

Create a named Range with Xl4Macro such as `SheetExists` and put this in the Refersto:  `=SUBSTITUTE(GET.WORKBOOK(1),"[" &GET.WORKBOOK(16)&"]","")`

Now on any sheet you can add this (array) formula and it will return back the sheet's actual index if its available.

`{=MATCH("Sheet1091",TRANSPOSE(SheetExists),0)}`

Just another way of doing things.:)